# Is this a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++

Being from Java background, Below is the C++ code from which  i would like to understand the conceptual usage  of `DList  listp;` member in `DListNode` class.

I could not understand, How `DList` type object can be casted to `DListNode` type in code  `node->add ( (DListNode*) this, this ) ;` and `this.tail = (DListNode*) this ;`

My goal is to convert this C++ code to Java.

```
class  DList
{
    private:
        friend class DlistNode;

        DListNode* head ;
        DListNode* dummy ;
        DListNode* tail ;
        int size;
    public:
        DList ( void ): dummy( NULL), size( 0 )
        {
            this.head = (DlistNode*) &dummy ; //this is sentinel
            this.tail = (DListNode*) this ;
        }
        void add_head   ( DListNode* node )
        {
            node->add ( (DListNode*) this, this ) ;
        }

        void add_tail ( DListNode* node )
        {
            node->add ( tail, this ) ;
        }

}
```

---

```
class DListNode
{
    private:

        friend class DList;

        DListNode* next ;
        DListNode* prev ;
        DList* listp;

    public:
        DListNode*  rem ( void )
        {

            if (listp)
            {
                next -> prev = prev ;
                prev -> next = next ;
                next = prev = this ;

                listp->size--;
                listp = NULL;
            }

            return ( this ) ;

        } 

        void  add ( DListNode* predecessor, DList *parent )
        {

            rem() ;

            if (!parent)
            {       
                listp = predecessor->listp;
            }
            else
            {
                listp = parent;
            }

            prev = predecessor ;
            next = prev -> next ;
            prev -> next = next -> prev = this ;

            if ( 0 != listp )
            {  
                listp->size++;
            }

        } 

}
```

---

My question:

1)
What is the purpose of `listp` being member of `class DListNode`?

2)
What is the purpose of `tail` member in `class DList`?

Comment: What do you mean by "How do i understand listp being member of class DListNode?" and what do you exactly mean by "Visualising"?

Comment: Good luck converting a linked list to Java. Are you aware that you don't get pointers in Java? Are you aware of ArrayList and things like that that are already built in?

Comment: @Yann4 Java references are more than enough to implement all kinds of linked lists. And C++ has `std::vector` and `std::list`, but that never stopped anyone from implementing their own list for education purposes.

Comment: @Yann4 Yes am aware. But am stuck because of `listp` being member of every node. I could not understand the conceptual usage here.

Comment: @delnan I agree with the educational purposes thing, but I was pointing out that there are much easier languages. Actually, typing this out, I concede to your point. I'd forgotten about the references in Java, it's been a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) listp is a pointer to the list as a whole. This allows operations on the list given only a node pointer.

2) tail is a pointer to the last item in the list. This allows some operations (like append) to be O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: As you said, `listp` is a pointer to list as a whole, why `listp` is part of every DListNode? I did not get when you say, `This allows operations on the list given only a node pointer`

Comment: Look at the line in `add()`: `listp->size++;`. Doing that without a list pointer is pretty much impossible.

Comment: i can push that addition stuff in DList() method, I think that is not the main purpose.

Comment: I agree there are other ways to implement a list, you asked about this one. The reason listp is in the node is because of that line. If you do not want that functionality, you could possibly get by without the pointer.

Comment: so this is a doubly circular linked list with sentinel. Sentinel's next points to first node of list. Sentinel's prev points to last node. Dlist's head points to the sentinel and DList's tail points to the last node, is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't believe the code compiles or runs correctly, so I think the answer is no, tho it may be intended to be what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid (or at least not a very good) implementation for a double-linked list.  The `DList` class is doing some really dangerous things that the `DListNode` is not aware of, and `DListNode` is not managing `DList`'s `head` and `tail` members at all.

The safest approach is to just use the STL `std::list` class and let it handle all of the details for you.  But if you must implement it manually, try something more like this instead:

```
class  DList
{
private:
    friend class DlistNode;

    DListNode* head;
    DListNode* tail;
    int size;

public:
    DList() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), size(0)
    {
    }

    ~DList()
    {
        while (head)
            delete head;
    }

    void add_head(DListNode* node)
    {
        node->add_head(this);
    }

    void add_tail(DListNode* node)
    {
        node->add_tail(this);
    }
};
```

```
class DListNode
{
private:
    friend class DList;

    DListNode* next;
    DListNode* prev;
    DList* listp;

public:
    DListNode() : next(NULL), prev(NULL), listp(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~DListNode()
    {
        remove();
    }

    void remove()
    {
        if (next)
            next->prev = prev;

        if (prev)
            prev->next = next;

        if (listp)
        {
            if (listp->head == this)
                listp->head = next;

            if (listp->tail == this)
                listp->tail = prev;

            listp->size--;
            listp = NULL;
        }

        prev = next = NULL;
    } 

    void add_head(DList *parent)
    {
        if (!parent)
            throw std::runtime_error("no parent specified");

        if (parent->head == this)
            return;

        remove();

        if (parent->head)
        {
            parent->head->prev = this;
            next = parent->head;
        }
        parent->head = this;            

        listp = parent;
        listp->size++;
    } 

    void add_tail(DList *parent)
    {
        if (!parent)
            throw std::runtime_error("no parent specified");

        if (parent->tail == this)
            return;

        remove();

        if (parent->tail)
        {
            parent->tail->next = this;
            prev = parent->tail;
        }
        parent->tail = this;            

        listp = parent;
        listp->size++;
    } 

    void add_before(DListNode *node)
    {
        if (!node)
            throw std::runtime_error("no node specified");

        if (node == this)
            return;

        remove();

        if (node->prev)
            node->prev->next = this;

        next = node;
        prev = node->prev;
        node->prev = this;

        listp = node->listp;
        if (listp->head == node)
            listp->head = this;

        listp->size++;
    }

    void add_after(DListNode *node)
    {
        if (!node)
            throw std::runtime_error("no node specified");

        if (node == this)
            return;

        remove();

        if (node->next)
            node->next->prev = this;

        prev = node;
        next = node->next;
        node->next = this;

        listp = node->listp;
        if (listp->tail == node)
            listp->tail = this;

        listp->size++;
    }
};
```

Comment: why would `DListNode` manage `DList`'s `head` and `tail` members? I think it is `DList`'s responsibility.is that correct?